# NSFetchedResultsController plus NSBatchUpdateRequest equals NSMergeConflict. What do I do wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I got a `NSFetchedResultsController` that I set up using a `NSManagedObjectContext`. I perform a fetch using this context.

I have as well a `NSBatchUpdateRequest` that I set up using the same `NSManagedObjectContext`. I execute the request using the same `NSManagedObjectContext`.

When I perform the request with the `NSBatchUpdateRequest`, I can see that all my data have been updated.
If I restart the app, any fetch using `NSFetchedResultsController` is working as well.

THe problem is when I'm not restarting the app and that I do both operations one after one, I got a `NSMergeConflict (0x17427a900) for NSManagedObject (0x1740d8d40) with objectID '0xd000000001b40000...` error when I call the method `save` from my context.

I know that the problem comes from concurrent change on the same data but I don't know what is the solution? One might be to go through the `NSMergePolicy` class, but I doubt that's a clean way to solve my problem.

What should I do? Have two different contexts ? (how?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it seems I might have found how to do it, but if you see anything wrong, please let me know.

When you do a batch update, you have the possibility to get as a result, whether nothing, the number of rows that were updated or a list of object IDs that were updated. You have to choose the last one.

Once you perform `executeRequest` from the context, you need to get the list of object IDs, loop through all of them to get every `NSManagedObject` into Faults thanks to the method `objectWithID` of the context object. If you don't know what Faults object are in Core Data, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html) is the explanation.

With every `NSManagedObject` you get, you need to refresh the context using its method `refreshObject`.

Once you've done that, you need to perform again the `performFetch` of  your `fetchedResultsController` to come back to where you were before the batch update.

Tell me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Here is the code:

```
let batchUpdate = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "myEntity")
batchUpdate.propertiesToUpdate = ["myPropertieToUpdate" : currency.amountToCompute]
batchUpdate.affectedStores = managedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores

batchUpdate.resultType = .UpdatedObjectIDsResultType

var batchError: NSError?
let batchResult = managedContext.executeRequest(batchUpdate, error: &batchError) as NSBatchUpdateResult?
if let result = batchResult {
    println("Records updated \((result.result as [NSManagedObjectID]).count)")

    // Extract Object IDs
    let objectIDs = result.result as [NSManagedObjectID]

    for objectID in objectIDs {
        // Turn Managed Objects into Faults
        let nsManagedObject: NSManagedObject = managedContext.objectWithID(objectID)

        if let managedObject = nsManagedObject as NSManagedObject? {
            managedContext.refreshObject(managedObject, mergeChanges: false)
        }
    }

    // Perform Fetch
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) {
        println("error: + \(error?.localizedDescription), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
} else {
    println("Could not update \(batchError), \(batchError!.userInfo)")
}
```

**EDIT**:
Here are two links for more explanations:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-batch-updates--cms-22164

http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-ios-8-batch-updating/

Comment: The Faults like is broken.  This may be the new location: [Faults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html)

Comment: Almost, you gave the `Mac` one. I updated with the iOS (which is probably the same). Thanks