# NSBatchUpdateRequest changes not reflected in MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, batch-updates, magicalrecord-2.2

I have tried to do a NSBatchUpdateRequest to change a property of several thousands NSManagedObject entities.

The changes are made in the database, but when I use Magicalrecord to retrieve the updated data, I get back the old data.

All the operations are performed on

```
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext].
```

I have also tried the solution mentioned in [NSFetchedResultsController plus NSBatchUpdateRequest equals NSMergeConflict.?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28675250/3913824) but it didn't work :(